# What is the term for "plain" non-flavored ice cream

Tags: language, ice-cream, american-cuisine

Me (russian) talked to my partner (american) about ice cream flavors. In Russia and post-USSR plain flavor (creamy-milky one) is extremely popular and often called [пломбир](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80). It is the default flavor, in contrast to American default, vanilla.

In the US though, this flavor of ice cream is not a real thing. Is there a term that I can use to find and buy that type of ice cream?

It seems like a [common question](https://www.google.com/search?q=plain%20ice%20cream), and some people call it "cream flavored ice cream", and russian->english translation can be "rich creamy ice-cream".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called "sweet cream" ice cream. If you make your own ice cream with something like milk, cream, eggs, and sugar, and you don't put any additional flavoring in it, it's called a "sweet cream base".

Comment: oh, that is something googleable!  https://mcconnells.com/products/sweet-cream-1

Comment: Crema is a standard in Italy as well. Cream and chocolate is the classic combination. Indeed in some countries even nearby is not, or less, common, too.

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing once in a restaurant, I think, under "whipped cream flavored ice cream" as part of a more elaborate dish (aka cream flavored cream, so I think it would count) so there may be other, odder terms the same thing pops up under.

Answer (score 1):

"Milk flavored ice cream"...or "milk ice cream" would work as search terms. I'm not sure you can purchase it in the US, but there are a few recipes on-line.